# Is it possible to combine mutiple charts with one navigator in highcharts stock?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm new to highcharts. The highstock charts is something like:

```
|-----------------|
|                 |
|      chart      |
|                 |
|-----------------|
|    navigator    |
|-----------------|
```

it include only 1 series.

Is it possible to implement multiple charts (each one contains 1 series), they share the same xAxis, and include them in one navigator, like this :

```
|-----------------|
|                 |
|      chart1     |
|                 |
|-----------------|
|                 |
|      chart2     |
|                 |
|-----------------|
|                 |
|      chart3     |
|                 |
|-----------------|
|    navigator    |
|-----------------|
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve it by defining multiple yAxis, their height and positions.

```
  yAxis: [{
    height: '33%',
    top: '67%'
  }, {
    height: '33%',
    top: '34%'
  }, {
    height: '33%',
    top: '1%'
  }],
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/adrqL1we/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.top